# Center Vertically Grid in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview

I'm trying to align center and vertically a `grid` element inside a `fragment`.

This is my xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    tools:context="it.gn.sfa.CatalogueFragment">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</FrameLayout>
```

It seems that `layout_gravity` nor `gravity` "centerize" (allow me this poetic licence) the grid.

**ADD**

XML of `gridView` content:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24pt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I do?

Comment: What is happening to your layout?

Comment: Literally nothing! It's top-aligned...

Comment: What about layout_gravity="center" in the GridView?

Comment: And what about `android:gravity="center"` in the `FrameLayout`?

Comment: Nope, none of them seems to work

Comment: Does your Fragment have anything more than that being added dynamically?

Comment: And what if you set a fixed width and height values?, like 100dp?

Comment: Nothing happens... Still not center-aligned

Comment: Could you please post your GridView item XML?

Comment: Run your code and check for yourself if it is centered or not

Answer (score 0):

The Grid View has match_parent for its height and its width meaning its taking up the entire parent.  It probably doesn't look centered because the image and the text inside the grid view is snapping to the top left of the grid view.  I would try wrap_content on the grid view height and width.  This will cause the Grid View container to only be as large as the contents inside it (textview and image).